# How to test function in useMemo hook with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component that uses useMemo hook. Component looks like:

```
    export const ContactListContainer = () => {
    ...
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('')

    const filterContactByQuery = (contact, query) => {
        const searchFieldValues = `${contact[FIRST_NAME]},${contact[MIDDLE_NAME]},${contact[LAST_NAME]}`.toLowerCase()
        return searchFieldValues.includes(query.toLowerCase())
    }

    const searchMemo = useMemo(
        () => functionUtils.defaultMemoize(query => contacts.filter(contact => filterContactByQuery(contact, query))),
        [contacts],
    )

    const filteredContacts = searchMemo(query)

    
    return (
        <ContactList
            onSetQuery={setQuery}
        />
    )
```

My task is to test memoization: I need to test that function 'filterContactByQuery' is not invoked in case of the same search query input.
I feel like I need to mock or spy on that function, but I can not figure out how to do it, coz it is inner function in component (i mean it is not exported or something like this).

I have draft of unit test (not working though):

```
imports of ContactList and ContactListContainer
test('should memoize filterByContacts()', () => {
        const setup = () => mount(<ContactListContainer />)
        //            const mockFilterContactByQuery = jest.fn()
        //            jest.mock('react', () => ({
        //                useMemo: () => mockFilterContactByQuery,
        //            }))
        const component = setup()
        component.find(ContactList).invoke('onSetQuery')('John')
        expect('filterContactByQuery').toHaveBeenCalled()
        component.find(ContactList).invoke('onSetQuery')('')
        expect('filterContactByQuery').not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    })
```

Comment: Where does `functionUtils.defaultMemoize` come from and what does it do?

Comment: It is project base memoize wrapper function. It retruns function and checks if last arguments passed to it were the same it just return result for that last arguments  without any calculations.

Comment: @Vight were you able to find the solution for the same ?

Comment: Any updates here? @Vight